# Displaying an image in html not working and showing orange square instead

Tags: html, css, image

I have been trying to print my logo on my menu bar. The problem is when I try to display the image it just shows an orange box. Here is an image of th orange box:

[image: Here is the orange box.]

Where the orange box is there should be an image. I have tried adding different images to see if it was something to do with my image but the other image did the same thing.

Here is some of my code:

```css
  .top-menu{
            background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.603);
            overflow: hidden;
            height:100px;
            font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
            font-family: 'Mooli', sans-serif;
           

        }
        .logo{
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height:100px
            
        }
```

```html
<div class="top-menu">
<img scr="logo.png" class="logo">
</div>
```

Thanks Matthew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div class="top-menu">
<img src="logo.png" class="logo">
</div>
```

The source attribute "src" was misspelled as "scr". That's why the image didn't display